# Cmake FILE() command prepends other path to provided file path

Tags: cmake, msys2

i have a problem with a cmake Findxxx script.

Im trying this on a msys2 shell inside win10 and my source code lies in `/home/adrian/dev/libosmscout`
Inside it i have a `build` dir from which i call `cmake ..`

Inside the problematic FindCairo.cmake file i have (among other things)

```
IF (CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS)
    IF (EXISTS "${CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS}/cairo-version.h")
        MESSAGE(STATUS "${CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS}/cairo-version.h")
        FILE(READ "${CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS}/cairo-version.h" CAIRO_VERSION_CONTENT)        
    ENDIF ()
ENDIF ()
```

Which results in:

```
-- D:/Dev/Compiler/msys64/mingw32/include/cairo/cairo-version.h

CMake Error at cmake/FindCairo.cmake:39 (FILE):
  file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):
/home/adrian/dev/libosmscout/D:/Dev/Compiler/msys64/mingw32/include/cairo/cairo-version.h
```

As you can see from the MESSAGE command the CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS variable gets filled correctly but the call to FILE(READ) somehow prepends my source directory.

What am i doing wrong? Why is he prepending?

Thanks!

Comment: msys may use unix-style path, i.e. `/d/some/path` instead of `D:/some/path`, meaning your file path `D:/Dev/Compiler/msys64/mingw32/include/cairo/cairo-version.h` is considered as a relative path so it is prefixed with your source directory to become an absolute path. Is that `FindCairo.cmake` a script you wrote?

Comment: Not technically mine but yes it is self written and not part of cmake. Even if it is as you described i couldnt find a way to disable this behaviour and it shouldnt happen in the first place in my opinion.